# Inline Images in Salesforce Community Chatter Answers

Tags: chatter, community, napili

I wanted to create a community that has the look and feel of a forum. Is there a way to add inline images to the posts that we make?

This will enable me to make more vibrant and catchy posts.

All that I can see is a way to attach images after the actual post. But I cant write a post that says something like

Check out the image below

-
[image]

This post is actually an example of what I want in the community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently SalesForce does not have a UI to add inline images to a post, however you can do it using the API. 
Documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_richtext_inlineimage.htm

You can always submit and Idea to the SalesForce Success Community. That is the best way for SalesForce to hear what features customers want the most. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch

Comment: Thank you Paul. Just one more thing. (I am new to this). Wanted to know if we can use connectapi for chatter answers in Community? or is it just chatter in internal feed view?

Comment: Yes Connect API Supports communities. Basically all the end points have a "communities/$communityId" version. See the linked page for more information.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/features_communities.htm